# AES encryption/ decryption with CBC and PKCS5Padding Python 3

Tags: python, encryption, aes, cbc-mode

I'm working on an integration that requires encryption of the requests and decryption of the response with the following details.

**Algorithm Used**: AES 128/CBC/PKCS5
**Initialization Vector (IV)**: {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x09, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}

**Message Digest Algorithm to be used as**: MD5(key)
Note: Key length is 32

I tried the code in the following link with no luck.

https://github.com/Bobspadger/sagepay-python/blob/master/sagepay.py

```
def encrypt( self, raw ):
    key = hashlib.md5()
    key.update("ABCDEF1234567890ABCDEF1234567890")
    key = key.hexdigest()

    raw = pad(raw)

    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, key)
    encrypted_text = binascii.hexlify(cipher.encrypt(raw))
    return encrypted_text.decode('utf-8').upper()
```

? ValueError: Error 65537 while instatiating the CBC mode

Also how can I use the provided IV as noticed that a randomly generated IV is used in many examples.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The IV you mean?

Comment: Not supported by whom?